# Replace one part of a specific line in a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, split, python-re

I have a `.conf` file which requires the names of the server certificate and key in line 51 and 52, as shown below:

```
http {
    ssl_certificate     /Eya/server_cert/Eya_selfsigned_09-03-2021.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /Eya/server_cert/Eya_selfsigned_09-03-2021.key;
     }
```

If the self-signed certificate files created (`server.crt` and `server.key`) DOES NOT have the same name as the one given in the `.conf` file, I have to replace only the names in lines 51 and 52 of the `.conf` file in the following manner:

```
ssl_certificate     /Eya/server_cert/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /Eya/server_cert/server.key;
```

Right now, I'm reading lines 51 and 52 of the `.conf` file, checking if the names are different. If it is different, I'm attempting to replace the name with the correct one, as follows:

```
if self.nginxConfRadioButton.isChecked():
    cerf = "    ssl_certificate     /Eya/server_cert/"
    cerfkey = "    ssl_certificate_key /Eya/server_cert/"
    searchfile = open("./nginx.conf").readlines()
    f = open("./nginx.conf", "w+")
    for i, line in enumerate(searchfile):
        if i == 50:
            fields = re.split('/Eya/server_cert/|;', line)
            field = fields[1]
            print(field)
            if (field != "server.crt"):
                cnfvalue = self.getNameValue("SERVER_CRT")
                print (cnfvalue)
                line = re.sub(".*\"", cerf + cnfvalue + ";", line)
                print(line)
        f.write(line)
   f.close()

def getNameValue(self, nginxConfValue):
    file = open('./cert.sh', 'r')
    for line in file:
        if nginxConfValue+"=" in line:
            line=line.replace(nginxConfValue+"=\"", "")
            cnfvalue = re.sub("\".*$", "", line).rstrip()
            return cnfvalue
    file.close()
```

I'm reading the name of the self-signed certificate from the `getNameValue()` function.
The output of the above code is as follows:

```
Eya_selfsigned_09-03-2021.crt
server.crt
    ssl_certificate     /Eya/server_cert/Eya_selfsigned_09-03-2021.crt;
```

Is it possible to replace ONLY `Eya_selfsigned_09-03-2021.crt` with `server.crt`? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groups in regex and them refer to them by \group_number in re.sub second parameter:

```py
crt_line = "    ssl_certificate     /Eya/server_cert/Eya_selfsigned_09-03-2021.crt;"
replacemant = "server"
re.sub(r"(.*\/)([^\/]*)(\..*)", r"\1" + replacemant + r"\3", crt_line)
>>>'    ssl_certificate     /Eya/server_cert/server.crt;'
```

(.*\/) - frist groups matches everything until last "/"

([^\/]*) - second group the thing you want to replace you could skip 
creating a group for this because you do no really need it in new version

(\..*) - third group "." + everything after id hence you do not have to use different version for different extensions.

Comment: This would work if I know that `Eya_selfsigned_09-03-2021.crt` is the name in the file. This was just an example I used. I'm trying to make the code dynamic so that even if the line has a different certificate name in the `.conf` file, my code wouldn't need to be changed. How can this be achieved? But your suggestion works well for this specific line! :)

Comment: Could you give me an example for which it would not work, because i think that I am not getting right what you need

Comment: With your updated answer, it works perfectly for a dynamically changing file. Thank you so much! :) Also, the explanation provided in your answer was easier for me to understand compared to the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) documentation.

Comment: It will fail if there is a file name without any directory before it as I look at it now i think it would be better to make a second pattern for it rather than modifying this one